# Record headphone output : Android

Tags: java, android, audio-recording, headphones

I have to record whatever user listening through headphones. Say for example, user listening song, talking to someone (in call) etc. Without headphones I was able to record but with headphones I ran out of luck. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077161/android-audiorecord-headphones-with-mic) link with all possible `Audiosource` and `MediaRecorder` but did not get expected result. So, help or any clue is greatly appreciated.

**Edit :** I thought to record headphone output but seems its not possible by Michael's answer. So, my requirement is as above. Any suggestion or clue about how can I achieve this is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no support in Android for recording output streams. There might be phones that support it in some fashion, but that'll be completely vendor specific and not something you can expect to work on any Android device.

Voice call recording is a special case, because voice call audio aren't regular streams that are managed by applications. Many Android devices support recording of both the voice call uplink and downlink using the VOICE_CALL/VOICE_DOWNLINK/VOICE_UPLINK audio sources.

When you say that you were able to record the playback without headphones, what I suspect actually happened was that the microphone picked up what was coming out of the loudspeaker, rather than some form of internal recording of output streams. Recording the loudpeaker output through the primary microphone is certainly one way of doing it, but the resulting recording is probably going to sound really bad.

Comment: @Micheal - ok. yes, without headphones, I am recording speaker output and thats working fine for me. As u explained abt voice call recording, I was wondering if I could do my recording in same way but now it seems not possible. Anyway, thank u for the detailed explanation...

Answer (score -3):

I usually just hook up my Android phone to a rig I originally made to record PlayStation 1 audio, into my computer.

- Stereo RCA cable terminating in dual female ends on each side ( 3 bucks ) combined with two stereo adapters that take the signal from two female RCA plugs, into a single standard headphone jack.
- Attach, place one of the now standard male stereo headphone plugs into phone, the other into the audio mic input of your computer.
- Fire up program like WireTap or similar
- Adjust settings so you can hear the received audio coming in through your streaming phone, and press the record button.

It may not be FLAC quality - but good enough. 
Total cost of equipment ( not including phone or computer): About **15** bucks.

Comment: OMG!!! What did I just read?